# Enqueue Script After TinyMCE initialized

Tags: tinymce

I am making a small live preview area inside a meta box using jquery where i need to get content from tinymce editor. But it seem my script loads before tinymce, this returns null when i try to get content from editor field.

**Enqueue:**

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpk_popup_admin_script', 100);

function wpk_popup_admin_script($hook) {
    global $post;
    if( 'edit.php' != $hook && $post->post_type != 'wpk_popup'  )
        return;

    if(is_admin()){
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

        wp_register_script( 'wpk-popup-admin', plugins_url('/js/admin.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), false, true);
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wpk-popup-admin' );
    }

}
```

Tried adding `editor` on dependency but its no use. The script prints just before the tinymce configuration.

[image]

**jQ Code for getting editor content:**

```
html += jQuery('#content_ifr').contents().find('#tinymce').html();
```

Which returns `NULL`.

**Resolved:**

Thanks to @birgire, I was able to solve the problem. Here is the final code.

```
add_action( 'after_wp_tiny_mce', 'custom_after_wp_tiny_mce' );
function custom_after_wp_tiny_mce() {
    printf( '<script type="text/javascript" src="%s"></script>',  plugins_url('/js/admin.js', __FILE__) );
}
```

For Getting or Inserting data I prefer to use tinymce api instead of jquery hack. So,

**Getting Data**

```
var content = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
```

**Inserting Content**

```
tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'Text to insert goes here')
```

Comment: did you try to use: tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent(); ?

Comment: @ungestaltbar: activeEditor is `NULL` too. My guess is i have to print the script after the tinyMCE initialization.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Adding scripts after TinyMCE:

You might check out the `before_wp_tiny_mce` and `after_wp_tiny_mce`hooks.

If you take a look at the file `/wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php` you can see that the `TinyMCE` settings scripts are not all loaded through the usual `enqueue` methods, but some are displayed via:

```
add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', array( __CLASS__, 'editor_js'), 50 );
```

where the `editor_js` method contains this code:

```
...cut...
            do_action('before_wp_tiny_mce', self::$mce_settings);
?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
                tinyMCEPreInit = {
                        base : "<?php echo self::$baseurl; ?>",
                        suffix : "<?php echo $suffix; ?>",
                        query : "<?php echo $version; ?>",
                        mceInit : <?php echo $mceInit; ?>,
                        qtInit : <?php echo $qtInit; ?>,
                        ref : <?php echo self::_parse_init( $ref ); ?>,
                        load_ext : function(url,lang){var sl=tinymce.ScriptLoader;sl.markDone(url+'/langs/'+lang+'.js');sl.markDone(url+'/langs/'+lang+'_dlg.js');}
                };
        </script>
<?php

                $baseurl = self::$baseurl;

                if ( $tmce_on ) {
                        if ( $compressed ) {
                                echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='{$baseurl}/wp-tinymce.php?c=1&amp;$version'></script>\n";
                        } else {
                                echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='{$baseurl}/tiny_mce.js?$version'></script>\n";
                                echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='{$baseurl}/wp-tinymce-schema.js?$version'></script>\n";
                        }

                        if ( 'en' != self::$mce_locale && isset($lang) )
                                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>\n$lang\n</script>\n";
                        else
                                echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='{$baseurl}/langs/wp-langs-en.js?$version'></script>\n";
                }
...cut...
            do_action('after_wp_tiny_mce', self::$mce_settings);
```

So if you want to add a custom script after all the `TinyMCE` scripts, you could emulate it's own (non-elegant) way above through the `after_wp_tiny_mce` hook:

```
add_action( 'after_wp_tiny_mce', 'custom_after_wp_tiny_mce' );
function custom_after_wp_tiny_mce() {
    printf( '<script type="text/javascript" src="%s"></script>',  plugins_url('/js/admin.js', __FILE__) );
}
```

This raises the question why not all the `TinyMCE` scripts are loaded via enqueue.

The hook `admin_print_footer_scripts` is too late for adding new scripts via enqueue, so it could be that some of these `TinyMCE` scripts must be loaded very late on the page.

### Capturing the editor content with jQuery:

You could also try this snippet, enqueued the normal way:

```
jQuery(window).load( function() {

    // test 1:
    //var ed = tinyMCE.activeEditor;
    //console.log( ed.getContent() );

    // test 2:
    // console.log( jQuery('#content_ifr').contents().find('#tinymce').html() );

    // test 3:
    if( jQuery('#content').length > 0 ){
        console.log( jQuery('#content').html() );
    }

});
```

to get the editor content.

Comment: @Sisir: it's great to hear it helped you with your problem **PS:** I'm not sure why the answer is now owned by **community wiki** after trying to improve it in more than 10 edits: `This post is community owned as of 4 hours ago. Votes do not generate reputation, and it can be edited by users with 100 rep.` I guess I didn't read the FAQ careful enough on this matter ;-)

Comment: I also Never knew.. :)

Comment: Oh my goodness... +1! I've been looking for this for months! You, my friend, are a god-send.  I do tons of developing in tinymce.. and was looking for a way to pass js vars ONLY to pages which loaded the tinymce editor.  THANK YOU!

Comment: @josh Happy to hear that, good luck with your project